# Python/jupyter: matplotlib freezes when I try to close a figure on a mac

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have recently installed jupyter/anaconda on my mac. Everything is working except when I try to make a figure:

[image]

When I try to close the figure, everything freezes. When I googled it, it seems to have been a problem for a while. However, I didn't find a solution, and I would greatly appreciate to find one. Thank you!

EDIT (working code now):

```
%matplotlib
from matplotlib.pylab import *
rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 300

def f(t):
    return t**2*exp(-t**2)

t = linspace(0,3,31)
y = zeros(len(t))
y = f(t)

plot(t,y)
show()
```

Comment: have you tried closing it using plt.close()

Comment: you can try this                            import matplotlib.pyplot import *        %matplotlib inline

Comment: @SRingne Hi! Once I run the block of code, how can I run 'plt.close()' please?

Comment: @Chandan Thank you for your answer. It allows me to see the graph in my notebook, but I would still like to have the option to see it on the side. :)

Comment: I think it will help you. Either you use the last code that I sent you or use this current one. Please don't use both at a time.     %matplotlib notebook

Comment: @Chandan I edited my question with %matplolib, and it worked! Jupyter says: "Using matplotlib backend: MacOSX" By curiosity, what does %matplotlib mean? If you post your answer, I'll choose it. :)

Comment: %matplotlib enables inline plotting without injecting your namespace. You'll need to do explicit calls to get matplotlib and numpy imported.